# Flutter - Stopwatch and Geolocator

Tags: flutter, gps, stopwatch

I am really stuck on this part of the code (I am a beginner on Flutter). I want to display the stopwatch timer and total distance from geolocator, but the stopwatch just updates when "geolocation" is moving.

When button is pressed I am calling this:

```
void _toggleListening() {
     if (_positionStreamSubscription == null) {
      const LocationOptions locationOptions =
          LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
      final Stream<Position> positionStream =
          Geolocator().getPositionStream(locationOptions);

      _positionStreamSubscription = positionStream.listen((Position position) {
        setState(() {
          _positions.add(position);
          _allPositions = _positions;
          _positionRealTime = position;
          updatePinOnMap();
          print('all lenght ${_allPositions.length}');
          totalDistanceAux = 0.0;
          for (var i = 0; i < _allPositions.length - 1; i++) {
            totalDistanceAux = totalDistanceAux +
                distance.as(
                  LengthUnit.Meter,
                  LatLng(_allPositions[i].latitude, _allPositions[i].longitude),
                  LatLng(_allPositions[i + 1].latitude,
                      _allPositions[i + 1].longitude),
                );
          }
          totalDistance = totalDistanceAux;
          print('total distance $totalDistance');
        });
      });
      _positionStreamSubscription.pause();
      _stopwatch.stop();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        if (_positionStreamSubscription.isPaused == true) {
          _positionStreamSubscription.resume();
          _stopwatch.start();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

and I am displaying with FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder<GeolocationStatus>(
                        future: Geolocator().checkGeolocationPermissionStatus(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<GeolocationStatus> snapshot) {
```

The distance and timer is working perfectly, the only problem is that timer just updates when there is some movement.
This is my first question at StackOverflow, sorry if I did something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rebuild a widget periodically, add the [timer_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/timer_builder) package and use it like that :

```
TimerBuilder.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1),
      builder: (context) {
        return YourWidget();
      }
)
```